# Variable/subroutine inheritance in parent/child structure

Tags: perl, inheritance, parent-child

I have a parent package and a few child and grandchildren packages:

```
#parent
package Mother;

sub new {
    my ($class, $args) = @_;
    my $self = bless {}, $class;
    return $self;
}

# load sub...
sub getGrandchildren {
    my ($self, $package) = @_;
    # find all grandchildren dynamicly
    my @grandchildren = ('Mother::Child::Grandchild');

    # load all found packages and load their config
    foreach my $grandchild (@grandchildren) {
        # require etc

        # load config
        my $c = $grandchild->getConfig();

        # damn ... $c is undef
        # I expected { x => 2 } from grandchild
        warn Dumper $c;

        $config{$grandchild} = $c;
    }
}

# this subroutine should be used
# by children and grandchildren
sub getConfig {
    my ($self) = @_;
    use no strict 'refs';
    return ${$self::."config"};
}
1;

# child
package Mother::Child;
use parent qw/Mother/;

our $config = { x => 1 };

sub new { 
    my ($class, $args) = @_;
    my $self = $class->SUPER::new($args);
    $self->getGrandchildren(__FILE__);

    return $self;
}
1;    

# grandchild
package Mother::Child::Grandchild;
use parent qw/Mother::Child/;

our $config = { x => 2 };

sub new { 
    my ($class, $args) = @_;
    my $self = $class->SUPER::new($args);

    return $self;
}
1;
```

if I call something like this:

```
my $child = Mother::Child->new();
```

all grandchildren are loaded and their configs should be loaded.

I am trying to achieve this by having a subroutine "getConfig()" which is only defined in the parent.

problem is that loading config with

```
$grandchild->getConfig();
```

returns undef.

I would like to avoid creating a subroutine getConfig() in every child and grandchild to return the right config (from child or grandchild).

Is it possible to do this with this child/grandchild structure? Or am I doing something totaly wrong?

**Solution**

As suggested by @bvr I replaced return value in getConfig with ${$self."::config"} and added "no strict 'refs'".

Comment: You're trying to create some kind of tree structure, I presume?  If so, why not just have a `Node` class and worry about whether or not each specific node has a parent, children, etc?  In fact, why not use (or build off of) a CPAN module such as [Tree](http://search.cpan.org/~rkinyon/Tree-1.01/lib/Tree.pm)?

Comment: what do you mean by "Node class"? I am pretty new to Perl and I did not know about Tree. on the other hand, I just want a basic parent-child structure and "use parent ..." is enough.

Comment: If you're trying to model a tree, then don't try to make a separate package for each generation (...what about a `Mother::Child::Child` class, or a `Mother::Child::Child::Child` class, etc?).  Just have a bunch of nodes and worry about how they relate to one another.  I'd recommend taking a look at Tree or at [`Tree::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~stevan/Tree-Simple-1.18/lib/Tree/Simple.pm).

Comment: Oh, and make sure to always, always, **always** `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. Every. Single. Time.

Comment: Thanks. I use warnings and strict. Always :).

Comment: Why do you want to avoid creating a method getConfig in every child and grandchild? It's the right way to do it. You can write them more snappily on one line like `sub getConfig { return { x => 1 } }`. If you don't want to repeat the `x =>` bit, then define a method in the base class `sub getConfig { my ($self) = @_; return { x => $self->getConfigXValue } }`, then you only need to define a method getConfigXValue in each subclass.

Comment: I already have them as "oneliner" but I wanted to avoid having absolutely same subroutine in every grandchild and I am keen to find out why the solution with inheriting does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some problems:

- the `Mother::Child`'s constructor does not return `$self`, so you don't get correct reference from `Mother::Child::Grandchild->new` call.
- `$self::config` is not correct syntax to access package variable. You need something like:

  ```
   sub getConfig {
       my ($self) = @_;
       my $class = ref $self;

       no strict 'refs';
       return ${$class . "::config"};
   }
  ```
- `getGrandchildren` gets configs incorrectly - where you get variable `@grandchildren` for instance.

**Edit:** added `no strict 'refs'` to `getConfig` subroutine to locally disable this checking.

Comment: I added "return $self" and defined @grandchildren array in the code example. That were just typos, I had that in my application code.

Comment: return ${$class . "::config"}; gives me this: "Can't use string ("::config") as a SCALAR ref while "strict refs" in use". $class is empty.

Comment: $class is obviously empty because ref($self) does not return anything. and $self in getConfig() is just a string "Mother::Child::Grandchild", not an object. I am obviously doing something wrong... and using ${$self . "::config"}; gives the same error: Can't use string ("Mother::Child::Grandchild::config") as a SCALAR ref while "strict refs" in use"

Comment: @toktok - so you don't want to call `getConfig` as method on instances? In that case it is good to avoid naming it `$self`. For the other part of question, you can disable strict for just local scope. See update in my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot. "my $class = ref $self" is always empty. I removed it and now I return ${$self . "::config"}; that works although I am not sure what is happening here and why strict complains.

Comment: additional question: is there a better way to do what I want: parent with a config-method inherited by all (grand)children who have their own config vairables?

Comment: @toktok - I actually rather meant `my ($class) = @_;` than use `ref`. Latter is useful when you supply instance (read reference to an object) and you want to get its class. To your additional question - it is not possible to inherit optionally, but you can detect presence of config within inherited method.